# How does kendo form validation custom required work?

Tags: validation, kendo-ui

I would like to add a required field to a Kendo form.
This works with:

```
validation: { required: true },
```

If I now want to set required myself in a function, this no longer works.

```
validation: { 
  required: function(){
             return true;
            }  
},
```

I have created an example: https://dojo.telerik.com/epEzewIt/5

If no entry is made in the "MultiSelect" field, the required variant as a function is no longer displayed: "MultiSelect is required" when it is empty.

How can I store required with a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to execute some code one time you can use an anonymous function like:

```
validation: { 
    required: (function(){
        return true; // run your rules here
    })()
```

But, as documentation suggests, those (required, max/min, pattern, etc.) are field attributes that map to HTML rules. So you can't pass a function.

Why not use the kendoValidator on your submit action. This can be used to validate all the fields and set custom messages.

Here are more details on how to use Kendo Validator to create custom validations:
https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/editors/validator/rules

There are a lot of examples there.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works wonderfully. My example: https://dojo.telerik.com/epEzewIt/12

Comment: I can't work so well with Validate, because the fields are generated dynamically and customized.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to achieve this and to have a event handler, you can use the following code:

```
validation: {
      validated: function (input) {
         //here you can place your code
         //you need to return true of false
         //e.g
         if(true){ return true; }
         return false;
     
      }
}
```

I had the same use case, as I was building it dynamically.

As you can see I was able to validate it:

[image]